# `cp` behaves differently after `mvn clean`

Tags: bash, shell-script, java, cp

So, I am working on a build script for a Java project, and I don't to run `mvn clean` during local development. So I have created a flag for developers `-k` which sets the variable `$DEV_BUILD` to `1`.

```
function build_war {
   if [ "$DEV_BUILD" -ne 1 ]; then
      mvn clean
   fi
   cd "$PROJECT_HOME"
   # Copy over static web files to ROOT
   mkdir -p "$WAR_HOME"

   cp -r js "$WAR_HOME/js"
   rm -r "$WAR_HOME/js/src/com"
   ...
}
```

When I run the script without the `-k` flag, the contents of `js` end up inside `$WAR_HOME/js` and `rm` command works. But if I run the script with the `-k` flag, there is a `js` directory inside the other and `rm` command fails.

Anybody have a clue why this might be occuring?

**Edit**

Based on @Kusalananda 's comment, I've added a few lines to the script to verify if the directory previously existed just to be sure.

```
if [ ! -f "$WAR_HOME/js" ]; then
  echo "js doesn't exist!!"
fi

cp -r js...
```

I'm get the "doesn't exist" message both with and without the `-k` flag.

Comment: Regarding your update: The test for existence of a _directory_ is `-d`, not `-f`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks! Fixed. And now I'm only seeing the message when the `-k` flag is set. I guess that's one mystery solved.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you’re not handling all this in your POM?

Comment: @StephenKitt Not sure what you mean? How?

Comment: You can build a WAR using Maven plugins, and copy resources etc. You shouldn’t need an external build script. (I’m not saying your approach is wrong, just that it might be simpler in the long run to replace your script with Maven configuration.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
cp source destination
```

and `destination` is an existing directory, then `source` will be put into that directory.

So `cp` behaves seemingly differently because the `js` directory in `$WAR_HOME` wasn't removed before copying it *again* with the same destination path.

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: I am quite sure that it makes a big difference for `cp source destination` whether `source` is a file or a directory... ;-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging Duh, yes. Thanks. That should have been `-r`, but I might just change the wording.